# Manually Created .deb, how do I upload to a PPA?

Tags: ppa, application-development, packaging, deb

I have a manually created `.deb`, and I'd like to upload it to a PPA.

My question is as follows:

- Is that possible?

and If so,

- how do I do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. Launchpad does not allow uploading of binary packages directly. It needs you to upload the `dsc` file along `changes` and original tarball. Then the build system builds it in a clean chrooted environment

How did you build this tarball? You had the packaging directory which was `debian/` directory? Right?

This is how I do:

1. Unzip/untar an upstream tarball. Say `foo-x.y.tar.gz`
2. Then put the debian/ directory inside that extracted directory
3. Put an entry in the debian/changelog file(either manually or using
   `dch -i`. If the version number reads say `x.y`
4. Rename that `foo-x.y.tar.gz` to `foo_x.y.orig.tar.gz`. Please see
   how the orig tarball should be named -
   `sourcepackagename_x.y.orig.tar.gz`
5. Now change to the directory where you have debian/ directory
6. Run `debuild -S -k9E6622AB` where 9E6622AB is my GPG key. You need
   to sign your packages.

If everything was fine, then three files are created - that `.orig.tar.gz` file, a `.dsc` file and a third is `.changes` file

I hope you would be using pbuilder/cowbuilder or any such builder of your choice to create the deb file.

Rest you have to do is

> dput ppa:yourusername/ppaname foo.changes

Ofcourse you need to create a PPA of that name

---

In case your dependencies are ruby gems which use incompatible packaging system, then you can use `postinst`, `preinst`, `postrm`, and `prerm` files for better control over the packaging process

Answer (score 4):

You can't upload a .deb, you need to upload the sources for the .deb for the PPA to make them (this, if your .deb is architecture-dependant, allows it to be built for both 32bit and 64bit then!). See [here](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/BuildingASourcePackage) on getting started with that.